# Error when installing "Maven Integration for Eclipse (Juno and newer)" in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin

I just downloaded and installed Eclipse Kepler (Java EE version). Then I was hoping to install Maven Integration for Eclipse (Juno and newer) from Eclipse Marketplace.

I kept getting the error message "There is nothing to update".

Anyone knows what went wrong and fix?

I am not sure this question is allowed in SO. If not, let me know. I will delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you downloaded the EE version, then the m2e is already installed along with the IDE.

On another note, with concise question content and proper formatting, your question is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your info! When I used Juno's EE version, I did not see any error when installing "Mave Integration for Eclipse (Juno)". Do you mean that m2e is not installed in Juno's EE version?

Comment: It is. EE comes with m2e.

Comment: I have the same "problem" as curious1. Worked fine in Juno (i.e. no error message) but Kepler simply won't let you install it. When I check my Eclipse Installation Details, the plugin (m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse) is not in the Plug-ins list.

Comment: Go to `Eclipse Marketplace` and search for the m2e integration for Kepler. The versions are different for each IDE.

Comment: @Roger Please [go here and read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18499019/1774643)

Comment: In Eclipse Marketplace it says "Maven Integration for Eclipse (Juno and newer)", I could not find any m2e integration that was specific for Kepler. Unfortunately the link in your answer is broken, though I think I will go with option 2 (just go with EE). Is there any need for m2e-WTP in EE?

Comment: @Roger Well if it says *Juno and newer* then it's most likely compatible with Kepler as well. Are you saying the link in my previous comment is broken? Weird, works for me. Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498938/problems-integrating-maven-with-eclipse-kepler

Comment: @GGrec Pardon me for being unclear. I was referring to the link in the post that you linked to, i.e. http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.0/1.0.0.20110607-2117/. =) Now, about "Juno and newer"... that is exactly what I was talking about in my first comment. Kepler will not let me install that plugin, even though it clearly states (in the name of the plugin - "Juno and newer") that it should work. However, if you tell me Kepler EE already has maven integration by default, it explains a lot, because I will not need - nor would it make sense - to install that plugin. Yes?

Comment: @Roger Short answer: Yes. :D Oh and by the way, I hope that the broken link was tried in the *Install New Software* view, correct?

Comment: @GGrec Oh I'm such a fool! It even says right below the link lol. Thank you GGrec for clearing things out!