# Problems integrating Maven with Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am totally new to working with **Maven in Eclipse**. I am using the latest verion of **Eclipse (Kepler)**. According other posts, as well as Eclipse's help page http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=//org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-127.htm , I am supposed to try to install new software within Eclipse IDE.

However, when I try to Add Eclipse's recommended m2e release, Eclipse gives me an error:

> Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases.
>   download.eclipse[...]releases is not a valid repository location.

Essentially I run into the same problem no matter which approach I take outlined on the Eclipse help page. Is there some other/better way to integrate Maven with Eclipse? Are there steps I should have taken before this? All I have done so far is install Eclipse. How can I successfully get Maven running?

EDIT: Now I am using Java EE and still run into problems when making a Maven project. I get a "Could not resolve archetype error" could this be because I'm behind a proxy?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy maybe?

Comment: doesn't eclipse kepler come with maven already available?

Comment: @jbx I'm at my work computer, so that's quite possible. How could I confirm this?

Comment: @Chaos that's what everyone tells me, but when I click New Project people say I should see a Maven project as an option, but I just get Java, CVS, and that's about it

Comment: @ManFriday, as the answer below says, try the EE version of Kepler

Comment: Check your browser and see if it has any proxy settings. It could be that Java is not using them (and thus Eclipse is not). You could also try to connect to the repository from the command line something like `telnet http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases`, just to confirm if it is a network issue. You should do as the others are suggesting and download the EE version, however Maven will still have a problem afterwards to download the libraries you need from the central repository if you have a proxy issue.

Comment: [Click here for a proxy test](http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Most convenient option:**

The reason you're getting that error is because that repo is deprecated, and it has been moved. Example of how the new repo looks:

`http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.0/1.0.0.20110607-2117`

Copy that in the **Install New Software** view, and you will see that it works.

---

**Other options:**

Install the Maven Integration from [Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org) (Help -> Eclipse Marketplace)

Download the [EE version of Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplerr) (comes with m2e)

Choose [your own release](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_updatesite_and_gittags) (bottom of the page) and use the **Install New Software** view.

Comment: I'd go with Option 2. I have the EE version of Kepler, I didn't have to do much to configure maven

Comment: @GGrec I copied the new link into the Install New Software view and got the same error. Maybe it's because I'm behind a proxy? I also am unable to create a Maven project in JEE Eclipse, as my edits to my original post reflect.

Comment: I'm newbie in maven technology and i already installed maven on my windows system, do i have to make a special configuration in eclipse after installing the plugin?thank you

Comment: @mohammedaminebourkadi A filesystem installation of Maven cannot be seen by Eclipse. You'll have to install the Eclipse Maven Plug-in (m2e) for Maven to work in Eclipse. If you don't plan to use Eclipse, then a Maven filesystem installation would suffice.

Comment: yes but when i install it do i have to change the user settings configuration from "C:\Users\Admin\.m2\settings.xml" to my "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.2" ??

Comment: @mohammedaminebourkadi This issue is not related to Eclipse. Plus, I don't think you have to modify anything after you've installed Maven as a standalone tool. Ask another question, in my opinion. :-)

Comment: When i donwloaded eclipse kepler ee by default i dont' see        "Maven ->Enable Dependacy Management"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here and the above answer didnt work for me. Although Maven is installed I cane update my dependencies on my folder the way I used to be able to do on Juno. What I did was used the pom.xml from my current project and pasted it into the pom of my new project I created specifically in Eclipse using new project->Maven.

This was eclipse knows its a Maven project and allows my all the benefits of being one.

Answer (score 0):

To install maven properly for eclipse you should set the correct repos as follow:

Help=>install=>
then work with 
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/

example of eclipse version : mars or kepler ..